# Remove files from Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I do not know why, but somehow two files were added to project with a mistake as you can see on screenshot. How can I safely remove them from Xcode project? I've already deleted them from disk, but `delete` button is grayed out in Xcode interface.

[image: delete is grayed out in xcode context menu]

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem today. The fix for me (on Mac) was:

1. Find **YourProjectName.xcodeproj** in finder.
2. Right click > Show package contents.
3. Inside there, right click on **project.xcworkspace** > Show package contents.
4. Open **contents.xcworkspacedata** (XML format) in any text editor and manually remove the references.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Do a clean of all targets and then remove the app from simulator. Finally, relaunch it.

Answer (score 1):

Quit Xcode and relaunch to fix it.

Comment: Build me a time machine 

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem, but you could give this a shot:

Close Xcode. Right-click your .xcodeproj file, show package contents. Make a copy of your project.pbxproj somewhere as a backup, then open the original in TextEdit. Find "MyClass.h" in the file. You should find a few lines containing it; just delete the entire line each time (including the line break). Do the same for "MyClass.m". Then save, and open your project.